# Can SQL Server use more than one index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

IMHO SQL Server can choose itself (unless being told) what is the *best* index to use for the query.

Ok

What about something like this (pseudo code):

```
select __a from tbl where __a not in
 (
   select __b  from tbl 

 )
```

(let's say we have `index_1` which is for `(__a)` and `index_2` which is for `(__b)`

Will SQL Server still use *one* index at execution or multiple indexes together...?

Comment: Why don't you look at the execution plan and see for yourself?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL to tell you the trouth   , I dont know where i can find this info in the plan...(which section)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+execution+plan

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL great answer. ( how old are you ?)

Comment: The problem with looking at an execution plan is that if it shows, for example, SQL Server is not using multiple indexes in this case can you say from that it will never be able to use multiple indexes in similar queries?  No, the same query will produce different execution plans if different data is loaded into the table, since execution plans depend on statistics - the distribution of data values saved in the table.  So execution plans are no good for negative proofs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, create your tables:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl(__a INT, __b INT);
```

Then create two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX a_index ON dbo.tbl(__a);
CREATE INDEX b_index ON dbo.tbl(__b);
```

Now populate with some data:

```
INSERT dbo.tbl(__a, __b)
  SELECT [object_id], column_id
    FROM sys.all_columns;
```

Now run your query and turn actual execution plan on. You will see something like this, showing that yes, both indexes are used (in fact the index on __b is used both for data retrieval in the subquery and as a seek to eliminate rows):

[image]

A more efficient way to write your query would be:

```
select __a from dbo.tbl AS t where not exists
 (
   select 1 from dbo.tbl AS t2 
     where t2.__b = t.__a
 );
```

Now here's your whole plan (again, both indexes are used, but notice how there are much fewer operations):

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your effort . I really appreciate it. big +1.